# Subdomain pointing to EC2 instance while domain is on S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a root domain like example.com. It's now hosted on Amazon S3. For that I followed this tutorial:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html

What would I have to do to have a subdomain like client.example.com to point to a EC2 instance?

client.example.com => ec2-XXX.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Is there like a tutorial out there explaining the steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two simple steps:

1. You would just need to add a new 'A' record to assign the ec2 ip address to that subdomain in your amazon route 53 dns (or whatever dns provider you are using) - very simple to do. Step one will have requests for that sub-domain routed to the ec2 instance.
2. Step 2 is to tell the web server you are running, when it receives a requests for that sub-domaain, what website should it serve up to the user - you do this by 'binding' the name to the directory/location thast has the website on your ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to read over the following from AWS

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-ec2-instance.html

It would also be better practice to assign your EC2 instance an Elastic IP address then forward requests to that IP.

> We recommend that you also create an Elastic IP address and associate
>   it with your Amazon EC2 instance. An Elastic IP address ensures that
>   the IP address of your Amazon EC2 instance will never change.